# Link CDN url to my product saved in magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, url, cdn

I want to Link CDN URL to my Product in magento. So basically all  the Images for the product will be fetched using the Image URL Rather than saving it on Magento Website (Project)

Is it possible to do so.?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set this for Products only, then you could create a custom product attribute, set the external link there. Customise the Product listing and details page to fetch image from the CDN link.

If you wanna fetch all your media from a CDN (content delivery network), you can tell Magento to use static files and media files from a CDN. Go to Stores > Configuration. Under the Web tab you can link the CDN in Base URL for Static View Files and Base URL for User Media Files. For more info about this aproach please refer https://magehit.com/blog/store-media-in-database-and-cdn-in-magento-2/

Hope it finds helpful.